# iPad; TableView full of arbitrary number of text fields and buttons in different rows. resignFirstResponder on all textfields when button is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, resignfirstresponder

iPad:

I have a tableView full of an arbitrary number of text fields and buttons in different rows.

When you press a button I a modal popup will popup.  If you press a button while editing a text field (and the keyboard is displayed on the iPad) something hilarious will happen.  The popover will be 75% off the corner of the screen (with a quarter visible in quarter.)

To avoid this bad behavior, how do you resignFirstResponder on all textfields in the table when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}
```

As long as the textfields' delegate are your current view controller, it should work fine :)

Comment: This doesn't work.  This only triggers when you hit done/enter/return in a field.  Clicking on a button when in the text field doesn't do anything.